# inserting into mysql an array of values

Tags: php, cakephp, phpmyadmin, cakephp-1.3

this is an edited code in which mr. Paulo Rodrigues, php curl is used to get the entries or data in the specified webpage. it will save in the file.txt. Open the file then gets the data of each entry then loop in order for the all data required in the entries is inserted.

```
$ch = curl_init("http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/?query=(annotation%3a(type%3asignal+confidence%3aexperimental))+AND+reviewed%3ayes&sort=score&limit=10&format=txt");
$fp = fopen("file.txt", "w");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

curl_exec($ch);


while (!feof($fp))
{

$array = array();
$index = -1;

foreach ($fp as $line) {
if (preg_match('#^ID#', $line)) {
    $index++;
}

$array[$index][] = $line;
}

foreach ($array as $block) {
$fields = array();

foreach ($block as $item) {
    if (preg_match('#^ID\s+(.*?)\s#', $item, $matches)) {
        print_r($fields['prot_name'] = $matches[1]);
        echo "&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp";
    } 
   else if (preg_match('#^OC\s+(Eukaryota)#', $item, $matches)) {
       print_r($fields['tax_lin'] = $matches[1]);
         echo "&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
             &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp";
    } 
    else if (preg_match('#LOCATION:\sMembrane;\s(.*?)\s#', $item, $matches)) {
        print_r($fields['sub_loc'] = $matches[1]); 

    } 

    }

    echo "<br />";

    if (!empty($fields)) {
    $f = implode(', ', array_keys($fields));
    $v = "'" . implode("', '", $fields) . "'";

    $sql = "INSERT INTO swissprot ($f) VALUES($v)";
    mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    }


   }
 }

curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

the problem is that there is a warning that displays: "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in this line. what might be the problem?

```
foreach ($fp as $line) {
if (preg_match('#^ID#', $line)) {
    $index++;
}

$array[$index][] = $line;
}
```

Comment: @PauloRodrigues may i also have your comment please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```
$webpagedata = file('http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/?query=annotation%3a%28type%3asignal+confidence%3aexperimental%29+reviewed%3ayes&sort=score&limit=10&format=txt');

$array = array();
$index = -1;

foreach ($webpagedata as $line) {
    if (preg_match('#^ID#', $line)) {
        $index++;
    }

    $array[$index][] = $line;
}

foreach ($array as $block) {
    $fields = array();

    foreach ($block as $item) {
        if (preg_match('#^ID\s+(.*?)\s#', $item, $matches)) {
            $fields['prot_name'] = $matches[1];
        } else if (preg_match('#^OC\s+(Eukaryota)#', $item, $matches)) {
            $fields['tax_lin'] = $matches[1];
        } else if (preg_match('#LOCATION:\sMembrane;\s(Single-pass)#', $item, $matches)) {
            $fields['sub_loc'] = $matches[1];
        }
    }

    if (!empty($fields)) {
        $f = implode(', ', array_keys($fields));
        $v = "'" . implode("', '", $fields) . "'";

        $sql = "INSERT INTO spdb ($f) VALUES($v)";
        mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    }
}
```

**Update:**

```
$ch = curl_init("http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/?query=(annotation%3a(type%3asignal+confidence%3aexperimental))+AND+reviewed%3ayes&sort=score&limit=10&format=txt");
$fp = fopen("file.txt", "w");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);

$file = file("file.txt");
$array = array();
$index = -1;

foreach ($file as $line) {
    if (preg_match('#^ID#', $line)) {
        $index++;
    }

    $array[$index][] = $line;
}

foreach ($array as $block) {
    $fields = array();

    foreach ($block as $item) {
        if (preg_match('#^ID\s+(.*?)\s#', $item, $matches)) {
            print_r($fields['prot_name'] = $matches[1]);
            echo "&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp";
        } else if (preg_match('#^OC\s+(Eukaryota)#', $item, $matches)) {
            print_r($fields['tax_lin'] = $matches[1]);
            echo "&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
             &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp";
        } else if (preg_match('#LOCATION:\sMembrane;\s(.*?)\s#', $item, $matches)) {
            print_r($fields['sub_loc'] = $matches[1]);
        }
    }

    echo "<br />";

    if (!empty($fields)) {
        $f = implode(', ', array_keys($fields));
        $v = "'" . implode("', '", $fields) . "'";

        $sql = "INSERT INTO swissprot ($f) VALUES($v)";
        mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    }
}
```

Comment: i have a concern, since its limit is 10, on the dtabase there are about 20 entries.. i noticed that some are repeated

Comment: Empty table before runing this code, maybe there are old data in database. I have the same code and show me 10 inserts.

Comment: ooops sorry for that, i reload it twice.. thank you very much!

Comment: can the phpmyadmin contain hundreds or thousands of entries? or do you know exactly how many entries it could contain?...

Comment: i really need all those entries in one run and about 5,000 of entries are in it, what things should i do? even hundreds will do

Comment: could you help me with this? tnx

Comment: @ansherina to not exceed the time limit for execution (usually 30 seconds) you can add `set_time_limit(0)` at the beginning for an unlimited time.

Comment: i have edited the code above and still have an error, may you help me with this? tnx

Comment: @ansherina First, you could have created another question, that it should get a reference for questions of others. Second, you opened the file with `fopen` for writing only and trying to iterate twice, with `while` and `for`. Check my updated answer.

Comment: yes. i have some problem with regex, how can i get a data with space for example a two-word "version number"?

Comment: in the following code (preg_match('#^OC\s+(Eukaryota)#', $item, $matches)) , how can get the first word next to OC? not only just Eukaryota, i tried to change it but it gets the next word of the last OC

Comment: Try this expression: `#^OC\s+(.*?)#`